# Scaling Java web applications with Ehcache

Tags: java, tomcat, caching, amazon-web-services, ehcache

I have a website hosted in AWS with 3 boxes (tomcat running on each) behind an Elastic load balancer(ELB). All the 3 boxes are running the same application. And each of them uses Ehcache through annotations on methods. For e.g.

```
 @Cacheable(cacheName = PRODUCT_CACHE)
 public List<Product> getProducts() {
 }
```

So each box has its own cache. Which means 3 times the memory usage on each box apart from the fact that the cache has to be cleared on each box in case a certain event is fired on any one box.

What is the better way to use Ehcache or any other caching library for this use case so that the memory consumption is reduced and cache busting is easier to manage?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can replicate the ehcache in a cluster, see [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication/index).

Answer (score 0):

1. While you are "wasting" memory, this setup is more resilient to failures (no cache lost if a node fails) and has less network overhead since all cache hits are local and roundtrips can have a bit of variance on AWS.
2. We've switched to Hazelcast and are very happy with it. It's a cluster by design and there you can easily tune the number of copies you want to keep. It also supports Spring's `@Cacheable`: http://hazelcast.org/use-cases/caching/#spring-cache

Answer (score 0):

Try [HybriCache](https://github.com/batir-akhmerov/hybricache) it is a hybrid cache library that uses both EhCache and AWS Elasticache Redis for fast caching in a cluster.